# Perl: Speeding up eval

Tags: perl, eval

`eval` is slow when done on a string: The string first has to be parsed before it can be executed.

I am looking for a way to cache the parsing, so that I can reuse the parsed string for yet another eval. The next eval will be the same code, but will not eval to the same value, so I cannot simply cache the results.

From the description I am looking for `ceval` from *[Eval::Compile](https://metacpan.org/pod/Eval::Compile)*.

But I cannot use *Eval::Compile*, as that requires a C compiler for the platform, and it is not given that the user has a C compiler.

So can I do something similar to `ceval` in pure Perl?

**Background**

[GNU Parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_parallel) lets the user give Perl expressions that will be eval'ed on every argument. Currently the Perl expressions are given as strings by the user and eval'ed for every argument. The Perl expressions remain unchanged for each argument. It is therefore a waste to recompile the expression as the recompilation will not change anything.

Profiling of the code shows that the `eval` is one of the bottlenecks.

**Example**

The user enters: `$_ .= "foo" and s/a/b/g`

A user's scripts are stored in `$usereval1` and `$usereval2`.

The user gives 10000 random arguments (strings) stored in `@arguments`.

```
sub replace {
  my ($script, $arg) = @_;
   local $_;
   $_ = $arg;
   # This is where I would like to cache the parsed $script.
   eval $script;
   return $_;
}

for my $arg (@arguments) {
   # Loads of indirect code (in the order of 1000 lines) that
   # call subs calling subs calling subs that eventually does:
   $replaced1 = replace($usereval1, $arg);
   $replaced2 = replace($usereval2, $arg);
   # Yet more code that does stuff with $replaced1 $replaced2
}
```

Comment: What exactly will be different in each invocation?

Comment: You can store a subroutine ref like this: `perl -lwe 'my $x = eval(q( sub { my $foo = shift; $foo*2; } )); print $x->(12);'` prints `24`. But then that begs the question, wouldn't it just be simpler to just write a subroutine? Are you sure you need dynamic code, or is this just a brute force solution? You need to share more details about your solution if you want a better answer.

Comment: The user provides the expression to be eval'ed, so yes I need dynamic code. Making an anonymous sub is not a bad idea. Is it faster though? Did you measure? If so, can you publish your numbers?

Comment: @TLP I did a minimal test. It looks as if it is 40x faster. Great!

Comment: @OleTange Allowing users to provide code to `eval` sounds like an exceptionally dangerous idea. Even assuming people are not actively trying to be malicious, you just know someone will eventually break something. If I were you, I would spend a bit more time on figuring out a safe way to do this.

Comment: @TLP The only ones in danger are the users themselves. The security situations is the same as if they wrote their own perl script: It will be run as their own user on their own systems risking their own data. You should submit your comment as an answer. Unless there is an even better answer, I will accept that in 24h.

Comment: @OleTange Indeed, but that might be dangerous enough for some people. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store a subroutine ref like this:

```
perl -lwe 'my $x = eval(q( sub { my $foo = shift; $foo*2; } )); print $x->(12);'
```

This prints `24`. You can reuse the code without the need to recompile it.

Comment: Measured speed up in the actual program (including all surrounding code): 1.5x. Not bad for a 5 line patch.

Comment: @OleTange Looking at your code, if you want the proper speed-up, you need to compile the `$usereval` outside the for-loop, such as `my $usereval1 = eval("sub { $string }")` and skip the eval inside the `replace` subroutine.

Comment: The 1.5x speed up only compiles the eval once.