# How best to dynamcially prepare and run user supplied Perl operators

Tags: perl, dynamic, eval

**Context:**

Perl script initializes itself based on a *user-supplied* **param-file**, then acts on a *user-supplied* **source-file** to filter out data and do other operations.

The **param-file** file contains partial perl expression, which are later suppose to be `eval`ed during runtime, for example:

```
match:!~  col:1  operand:1|2|3
match:=~  col:1  operand:[^123]
match:=!  col:1  operand:^DATE
match:=~  col:1  operand:^(?:\s|DATE)
match:-~  col:1  operand:^\s
match:eq  col:7  operand:CA
match:eq  col:7  operand:DI
match:ne  col:1  operand:ACCOUNT
match:ne  col:1  operand:POSITIONS
match:==  col:8  operand:999
match:!=  col:8  operand:999
```

Hmm, and how about something like this? maybe later, but I need that too

```
match="ne list" '11, 71, 7'
```

Briefly, my perl will get the match operator from the user and then needs to filter out (or in) records from the **source file** based on the other params.

One and simple approach, is `eval`:

```
next unless eval "$value $match $operand";
```

Now, given that I know that the `$match` will always be the same, the use of `eval` on EACH input of the source-file, sounds like an overkill.

```
if ($match eq '!~')
{
    next unless $value !~ /$operand/o;
}
elsif ($match eq '=~')
{
    next unless $value =~ /$operand/o;
}
elsif ($match eq 'eq')
{
    next unless $value eq $operand;
}
...
```

And I was thinking of having a hash lookup, not sure how to do that. (I wonder on that too), also thinking of closures ...

I'm looking for best and most efficient approach?

Comment: Using the `eval` is the least code to maintain. See [Eval::Compile](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Eval-Compile-0.10/lib/Eval/Compile.pm) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24911132/perl-speeding-up-eval) about speeding up the eval.

Comment: I'm not sure there's ever a reason to use `/o`. Using it here makes no sense.

Comment: @ikegami I see [your point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550258/does-the-o-modifier-for-perl-regular-expressions-still-provide-any-benefit) on `/o` thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using `eval EXPR`:

```
$match =~ /^(?:[=!][~=]|eq|ne)\z/
   or die("Unrecognized operator \"$match\"\n");

my $rv;
eval("\$rv = \$value $match \$operand; 1")
   or die $@;
```

Using a dispatch table:

```
my %ops = (
   '=~' => sub { $_[0] =~ $_[1] },
   '!~' => sub { $_[0] !~ $_[1] },
   '==' => sub { $_[0] == $_[1] },
   '!=' => sub { $_[0] != $_[1] },
   'eq' => sub { $_[0] eq $_[1] },
   'ne' => sub { $_[0] ne $_[1] },
);

my $op = $ops{$match}
   or die("Unrecognized operator \"$match\"\n");

my $rv = $op->($value, $operand);
```

I don't see how closures could be of any use.